# The debug gem's binding.break creates break point but no console prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, puma, windows-terminal

I have a Rails 7 application using `gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]` for debugging.  I am also using WSL2 and Windows Terminal on Windows 11 for my development environment in case that's part of the issue I'm about to describe.

If I try setting a `binding.break`, breakpoint in my application it breaks correctly but doesn't give me a console prompt.  I'm not sure if there is something I'm not doing as this gem is new to me.  I'm attaching an example output from my Puma output.

**Update:** Also should note that when using this in my tests, it does work as expected.

**Another Update:** I noticed that the break points work if I use `rails s` to start the server but not when I use `bin/dev`.

**Another Update:** Here is the bin/dev file contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! command -v foreman &> /dev/null
then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add the code present in the bin/dev file in the question?

Comment: @PedroPaiva, code in the bin/dev file?  I can but just to be clear that's not a file I created. I assume that is in Rails 7?  But I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: I asked just to be sure, thank you. I had a similar problem with that on my Linux environment. I replaced foreman with overmind and it worked like a charm, but unfortunately, at the moment, Overmind supports Linux, *BSD, and macOS only. Would you like for me to give you more details about that?

https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind#installation

Answer (score 0):

`foreman` doesn't tell its subprocesses that they are running with an interactive terminal.

When you run tests it isn't running through foreman.

When you run the server with `rails s` it isn't running through foreman.

In both of those cases, your app knows it has an interactive terminal and syncs input and output.

Since you're running under WSL2, you should be able to run `overmind` which seems to handle things differently. (Or just run the services from your procfile directly yourself in different consoles and then run `rails s`).